# Splitting a String into only 2 parts

Tags: c#, .net

I want to take a string from a textbox (txtFrom) and save the first word and save whatever is left in another part. (the whatever is left is everything past the first space)

Example string  = "Bob jones went to the store"

array[0] would give "Bob"
array[1] would give "jones went to the store"

I know there is `string[] array = txtFrom.Split(' ');` , but that gives me an array of 6 with individual words.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `String.Split(Char[], Int32)` overload like this:

```
string[] array = txtFrom.Text.Split(new char[]{' '},2);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You simply combine a split with a join to get the first element:

```
string[] items = source.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string firstItem = items[0];
string remainingItems = string.Join(" ", items.Skip(1).ToList());
```

You simply take the first item and then reform the remainder back into a string.

Comment: I think you want a space delimiter in your Join.

Comment: This is a good answer though the OP is using a space for a separator and not a comma.  I think your example is clear enough though.

Comment: Yeah, I usually do a comma, my bad! TOo many comma delimited strings in this world!

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload of the [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method which takes an integer representing the number of substrings to return.

So your method call would become: `string[] array = txtFrom.Text.Split(' ', 2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',' };
string text = txtString.Text;

string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars, 2);

txtString1.Text = words[0].ToString();
txtString2.Text = words[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try RegularExpressions

```
Match M = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(source,"(.*?)\s(.*)");
M.Groups[1] //Bob
M.Groups[2] // jones went to the store
```

The regular expression matches everything up to the first space and stores it in the first group the ? mark tells it to make the smallest match possible.  The second clause grabs everything after the space and stores it in the second group

Answer (score 0):

and as method with long delimter:

```
public string[] SplitInTwoParts(string source, string delimiter){
    string[] items = source.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    string firstItem = items[0];
    string remainingItems = string.Join(delimiter, items.Skip(1).ToList());
    return new string[] { firstItem, remainingItems };
}
```