# How to split two strings and swap sliced parts in C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have an array and each index contains a string with four characters. I need to select a random point in the string and then slice `stringaArray[0]` and `stringaArray[1]` at the same point and swap their sliced parts and add these to `splicedStringArray[0]` and `splicedStringArray[1]`.

I know how to use split in C# and I have been experimenting with this, but it will only split the string into characters, not parts. I ask this question because my way of thinking is to create lots of variables to hold temporary strings then add them to the `splicedStringArray[]`.

Here is my latest attempt to find the start middle and end of a string and hopefully copy whatever I want to variables to make new strings and then store these in teh second array:

```
            string s = stringaArray[0];
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();

            int amount = charArray.Length;

            int findMiddle = amount / 2 + 1;

            int midchar = findMiddle - 1;
            int findLast = amount - 1;


            char fchar = charArray[0];
            char mchar = charArray[midchar];
            char lchar = charArray[findLast];
```

I was also looking at the string builder class in C# and wondering if there was something there I could use, but I think I will spend a lot of time on this and and develop the worst solution so any advice on how to do this would appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you have tried?

Comment: Can you post an example of your swap and slice?

Comment: I have edited this since this morning allow me to back track and get this code I will ass it then thanks!

Comment: @TimSchmelter You were probably being sarcastic, but just in case you weren't, he meant *ask* :)

Comment: I dont have the slice part any more for some reason. I got the slice help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906572/splitting-a-string-into-only-2-parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For splitting at the exact position, use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx). This way you can split *up to* certain point and *from* certain point. The simplest solution is similar to this:

```
var offset = 1;
splicedStringArray[0] = stringArray[0].Substring(0, offset) + stringArray[1].Substring(offset);
splicedStringArray[1] = stringArray[1].Substring(0, offset) + stringArray[0].Substring(offset);
```

Disclaimer: the code is written without testing.